# Restrict JIRA project access from one project to other project

Tags: jira, updates, restriction, jira-agile

We have multiple projects in JIRA, lets say Project A, Project B, Project C, Project D etc. Recently I was requested to create a new **Project E**, But I don`t want Project E members to access all other projects( Project A-D).

Earlier, I used to created group and assign it to the project so that Project E is only accesses the particular project and not the other projects.

Recently, after the update I got in JIRA. I am not able to restrict the user and project. can someone guide me?

I want to create new Project E but its members should not be able to access the other Projects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for info on how to configure project permissions.

Jira is quite flexible.

Each project has a project scheme. Each project scheme mentions who has certain permissions. For each permission (e.g. Browse Issues), you decide which users/groups/roles are assigned to it.

So it sounds like you want to do something like this:

- Create a group for users that need access to projects A, B, C and D
- Create a permission scheme that lists this group in its permissions and configure projects A, B, C and D with this scheme
- Create a group for users that need access to project E. Make sure that these users do not belong to the group intended for projects A, B, C and D
- Create a permission scheme that lists this group in its permissions and configure project E with this scheme.

This is explained in more detail on the [Managing project permissions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver075/managing-project-permissions-935391141.html) page of the Jira docs.